# Need a procedure for the below code, i.e, extracting Rs. from text

Tags: sql, procedure

```
CREATE TABLE #income (clientIncome NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO #income
(
    clientIncome
)
VALUES ('INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-'),
('INCOME FROM WHOLE  SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/-'),
('TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/-'),
('TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/-'),
('[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES]'),
('NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-');

SELECT i.clientIncome,
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) != 0 THEN
               CAST(replace(SUBSTRING(
                    i.clientIncome,
                    CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) + 3,
                    CHARINDEX('/-', i.clientIncome) - CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) - 3
                    ),',','') AS NUMERIC)
           ELSE
               NULL
       END income
FROM #income AS i;

DROP TABLE #income;
```

Comment: Do you just want a function that takes a string and returns a number based on this logic? Or does the procedure need to return tabular data? Are the strings stored in a permanent table somewhere that the procedure will read?

Comment: that takes a string and returns a number based on this logic

Comment: Extracting rupee sign from the text and display number, eg₹12, prints 12

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(@inputstring nvarchar(max))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret int;
    SET @ret = CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('RS ', @inputstring) != 0 THEN
               CAST(replace(SUBSTRING(
                    @inputstring,
                    CHARINDEX('RS ', @inputstring) + 3,
                    CHARINDEX('/-', @inputstring) - CHARINDEX('RS ', @inputstring) - 3
                    ),',','') AS NUMERIC)
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
    RETURN @ret;
END;
```

This simply puts your current logic in a function which can then be used. e.g. `SELECT dbo.myfunction('INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-')` or `SELECT dbo.myfunction(mycolumn) FROM mytable`

Here is a [fiddle of it](https://dbfiddle.uk/brd7APOW).